# Rails ActiveRecord has_one and belongs_to reloading association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, belongs-to, has-one

I have four models

```
class Votation
  belongs_to :quorum

  def calc
    return self.quorum.calc
  end

end

class Quorum
  has_one :votation
  ...
end

class NewQuorum < Quorum
  def calc
    do stuff and call
    self.votation.attribute_a
  end
end

class OldQuorum < Quorum
  def calc
    do stuff and call
    self.votation.attribute_b
  end
end
```

I have loaded the votation into a `@votation` object and eager loaded the associated Quorum.

The problem is that when I call `@votation.calc`, ActiveRecord execute a SQL select to load the votation again when it has to execute `self.votation.attribute_a` for example.

`SELECT "votations".* FROM "votations" WHERE "votations"."quorum_id" = $1`

how can I avoid this select from being executed?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `:inverse_of` option when specifying the association to prevent another select statement from being executed.

So your models would look like:

```
 class Votation
   belongs_to :quorum, inverse_of: :votation
 end

 class Quorum
   has_one :votation, inverse_of: :quorum
 end
```

Reference: http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods/belongs_to